# onlyoffice nextcloud "document could not be saved" nodeJS - postData error

Tags: node.js, docker, callback, nextcloud, onlyoffice

Using nextcloud 17.0.2 and documentserver:5.4.2.46 docker images on same server. Both services are working but opening a file in browser displays "The document could not be saved" error message.

Error message points to this url https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/troubleshooting explaining that the callback handler is not working. "The document editing service cannot connect to the document storage service at the editorConfig.callbackUrl address."

Unsure how to set the callbackUrl any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: document could not be saved]

```
==> /var/log/onlyoffice/documentserver/docservice/out.log <==
[2020-01-08T01:32:36.164] [ERROR] nodeJS - postData error: docId = 173335947;url = http://nc.example.com/apps/onlyoffice/track?doc=eyJ0eXAiO
iJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJtaWtlIiwiZmlsZUlkIjoxMTIsImZpbGVQYXRoIjoiXC9hYmMuZG9jeCIsInNoYXJlVG9rZW4iOm51bGwsImFjdGlvbiI6InRyYW
NrIn0.EWo6KBqF6-ZtcvfrVlvJR5UFLDjmxTt8XKsNgylBv8s;data = {"key":"173335947","status":1,"users":["ocxhbukekiw0_mike"],"actions":[{"type":1,"use
rid":"ocxhbukekiw0_mike"}]}
Error: Error response: statusCode:301 ;body:
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

    at Request._callback (/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/server/Common/sources/utils.js:301:23)
    at Request.self.callback (/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server address for internal requests from the Document Editing" defaulted to http://nc.example.com which is wrong, https://nc.example.com is correct. Also must us FQDN not docker service name.

[image: document could not be saved]